# Why is it centered on desktop and not centered on device?

Tags: android, html, ios, css, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an ios app.

It starts with a menu and used this **CSS** to center it:

```
.center{
    /** CENTRAR NO ECRA * */
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);   
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Here is the **HTML**:

```
<div data-role="page" id="loginPage">
            <script>
                login.init();
            </script>
    <div class="ui-corner-all ui-corner-bottom ui-content">

        <div class="center">
            <img id="imgLogoLogin" src="img/fvlogo.png" alt="LOGO"
                 class="imgLogoCenter" width="250px" />
            <h1>Welcome</h1>


            <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="username"
                   id="username" autocomplete="on" placeholder="username"
                   onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
                   onblur="this.placeholder = 'username'" value=""> <input
                type="password" data-clear-btn="true" name="password" id="password"
                placeholder="password" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
                onblur="this.placeholder = 'password'" value="">
            <p id="txtErro"></p>
            <a href="" id="btnLogin" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Entrar</a>
        </div>
```

**The problem is:**

I thought I was going fine because in my desktop the menu was well centered. But yesterday I tried to run the app in an Ipad and the menu wans't centered anymore.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: How are you displaying this in the iOS app? In a webview?

Comment: @thatidiotguy  I'm not using any browsers in the Ipad. Not sure if i answered your question

Comment: You did not. You are showing us HTML and then talking about an iOS application. How are you displaying this web page in an iOS app?

Comment: I'm programing as if i'm making a website. and then i use the phonegap to convert it to ios

Comment: I use the google device mode in inspect element to simulate an ipad and see what I am doing. But in this mode the menu is centered but in a real ipad is not

Comment: @thatidiotguy did i answer your question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the **CSS**

Instead of:

```
.center{
    /** CENTRAR NO ECRA * */
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);   
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Should be:

```
.center{
    /** CENTRAR NO ECRA * */
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);   
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

To work on ios, the `transform` needs the prefix `-webkit-`

Answer (score 0):

Use more divs!

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class = "inner">
            <!-- Information here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /* set width here */
}
```